# How to animate some parts of an image using CSS?

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I have an image and I want to animate some parts of it using CSS.

So, I got a question:

1. Can I animate some parts of an image with AutoPlay? 
   I mean after some period of time it should animate itself without reloading the entire page. Possible?

Image example:
[image: The disk with 24 has to slightly appear rounding (like a wheel) from left, the text "hours" should slightly appear from right when the circle is in its place, then all this should repeat in 1 min or 30 seconds ;)]

The disk with 24 has to slightly appear rounding (like a wheel) from left, the text "hours" should slightly appear from right when the circle is in its place, then all this should repeat in 1 min or 30 seconds ;)

Thank you for your help!

I want it to be so.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Using only a single HTML element and CSS (and an optional background image)

#### It looks like these, but smoother!

[image: GIF Example with images] - with images

[image: GIF Example] - with no images (further styling needed)

**Compatibility:** [IE10+ and all modern browsers. Chrome currently requires the `-webkit-` prefix.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation)

### The Text

- The text inside the `<h6>` is hidden with `text-indent: -9999px`
- The text shown is created with 2 [pseudo element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) children of the `h6` parent,  `:before` and `:after`
- The pseudo element children are hidden outside the parent thanks to `overflow: hidden` and `left:100%` / `right:101%`(the extra one percent hides the borders edge)
- The "hours" text animation is delayed by 2 seconds

### Inside the Keyframes

- At 10% the "24" text is rotated 180 degrees
- At 25% to 95% the "24" and "hours" text is moved to the centre with `transform: translateX`
- At 100% the text is moved back outside with `transform: translateX(0)` and the "24" is rolled out with `rotate(180deg)`

### Complete Example

#### Using background images

```css
h6 {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  text-indent: -9999px
}
h6:before,
h6:after {
  position: absolute;
  text-indent: 0;
}
h6:before {
  content: '';
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ad9Tn.png) no-repeat;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  right: 101%;
  top: -3px; /*just for this example*/
  -webkit-animation: roll 10s infinite linear;
  animation: roll 10s infinite linear;
}
h6:after {
  content: '';
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/VT4GI.png) no-repeat;
  left: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-animation: slide 10s 2s infinite linear;
  animation: slide 10s 2s infinite linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes roll {
  10% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  20%,
  95% {
    transform: translateX(50px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0) rotate(180deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes slide {
  10%, 75% {
    transform: translateX(-50px);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
@keyframes roll {
  10% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  10%,
  95% {
    transform: translateX(50px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0) rotate(180deg);
  }
}
@keyframes slide {
  20%, 75% {
    transform: translateX(-50px);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<h6>24 Hours</h6>
```

#### Using no images

```css
h6 {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  text-indent: -9999px
}
h6:before,
h6:after {
  position: absolute;
  text-indent: 0;
}
h6:before {
  content: '24';
  right: 101%;
  border: solid 2px #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 4px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  line-height: 10px;
  -webkit-animation: roll 10s infinite linear;
  animation: roll 10s infinite linear;
}
h6:after {
  content: 'hours';
  left: 100%;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  line-height: 20px;
  -webkit-animation: slide 10s 2s infinite linear;
  animation: slide 10s 2s infinite linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes roll {
  10% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  20%,
  95% {
    transform: translateX(50px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0) rotate(180deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes slide {
  10%,
  75% {
    transform: translateX(-45px);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
@keyframes roll {
  10% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  10%,
  95% {
    transform: translateX(50px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0) rotate(180deg);
  }
}
@keyframes slide {
  20%,
  75% {
    transform: translateX(-45px);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<h6>24 Hours</h6>
```

Comment: Yes, it is great for me! Thank you a lot. So, to have what I really need as on the image I could use my own font, yes? But how to make that arrow also?)

Comment: The easiest way would be to break it into the left and right images, I created two badly cropped images to create another example using background images (added to my answer). Have a play around with that.

Comment: Does rotation work in all browsers? Seems it doesn't in FireFox.

Comment: My appreciation to you does not have borders :-)

Comment: I have an issue. I need it to have width:156px; and at the right. See the image above, please. How to do it?

Comment: @ZafarGilfanov - An easy way would be to float the parent of the phone number and 24 hours text to the right. [Like this example](http://jsbin.com/jurofe/3/edit) :)

Answer (score 0):

CSS isn't going to do it. Probably the best option is to simply create a .gif using a program like photoshop

Answer (score 0):

You could animate everything together if you either cut out the individual elements as individual images and then position them accordingly inside a container, then animate the individual images the way you want to.

Or if you have access to the vector file, you can use SVG for each element of the image for the animation. This way you can more easily cut an element and paste it as code in your HTML.

So yes you can but only if you cut the image into individual pieces and animate these.

EDIT://

Yes you can add an AutoPlay. You can do this using CSS Keyframes ([link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp))

SVG is vector based graphics that is fairly new to the web. Since SVG is vector based it can be resized to any size whilst keeping the resolution. If you want to know more about vector graphics and SVG, you can look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics).

The only reason I mentioned SVG is because it's a bit easier to use since it's similar to HTML and each element in a SVG can be used as a selector in both CSS and Javascript(jQuery) for changing style and or animate it.

Comment: Okay. It is a good way to do it. How can I put an AutoPlay there? Can you make an example for me to show how to do it?)

Comment: What is SVG? And how do I make animations with SVG? Explain, please. Thx.

Comment: Apparently now I can leave comments, so check the answer again for updated info based on your questions. Hope it helps!

Comment: Do you have access to the vector version of the logo or just the .png / .jpg image?