# Make different parts of image transformable

Tags: css

I have this image and I would like to make different parts of it hoverable and transformable to use it as some kind of menu.
E.g. when you hover over the sun it get's bigger.
I tried some things with svg and it works fine with single paths, but I don't manage to apply effects to an "object" which has several colors, like the sun.

[image]

Comment: Try wrapping all the sun's SVG elements inside a `<g>` element and transform that one. `g` means "group"

Comment: You could also break the image intro parts (lossless *PNG* would work well here) and re-construct the image with CSS, combining all the parts so it will look like the original design. Then you'll be free to do whatever using CSS

Comment: related - https://stackoverflow.com/q/29334896/104380